# How to download images from Url and save it in temp folder in WPF C# project?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have maintained a dictionary having key-value pair as previewUrl and localPath. Now i want to download these images using previewUrl and save them into temp local folder and return localpath.

PreviewUrl Ex-  `https://dxntypz00uefe.cloudfront.net/qamangospring/us-east-1/pulse/ankurqa/images/users/3182/1620216873296_newFile_mobile.jpeg`

Answer (score 3):

Just download the file from the URL, e.g. like this:

```
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
  {
      var address =  "https://dxntypz00uefe.cloudfront.net/qamangospring/us-east-1/pulse/ankurqa/images/users/3182/1620216873296_newFile_mobile.jpeg";

      var savePath = Environment.GetFolderPath("your save path");
      var fileName = Path.Combine(savePath, "newFile_mobile.jpg");

      client.DownloadFile(address, fileName);

      //fileName  is your local path
  }
```